# Delete from HashTable based on value in C++ not using STL

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I am implementing a program to search string in a file.What i do is i ask user to enter the file name and contents of the file and then tokenize the contents with space as delimiter and create a hash table of it. example:

`filename-abc.txt content- i am bad than u filename-xyz.txt content-u r 
awesome`.

My hash map looks like this:

```
i->abc.txt
m->abc.txt
bad->abc.txt
than->abc.txt
u->abc.txt->xyz.txt
r->xyz.txt
awesome->xyz.txt
```

I have to do many operation on it but one such operation is `delete the filename` that means if the user asks to delete xyz.txt, the hashmap should look like

```
i->abc.txt
m->abc.txt
bad->abc.txt
than->abc.txt
u->abc.txt
```

All this is happening in memory and i have created my own `hashnode` and `hashmap`, not using `C++ STL`.

My HashNode looks like this

```
  class HashNode

    {

        public:

        int key;

        string value;

        HashNode* next;

            HashNode(int key, string value)

            {

            this->key = key;

            this->value = value;

            this->next = NULL;

            }

    };
```

Hashmap is like this

```
 class HashMap

    {

        private:

            HashNode** htable;

        public:

            HashMap()

            {

                htable = new HashNode*[TABLE_SIZE];

                for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)

                    htable[i] = NULL;

            }
```

How would i implement the delete file operation.

Comment: As per you code, deleting a `filename` is simply a task of deleting a node from singly linklist. But you need to parse the linklist which is present on every index of your hashtable. Instead of parsing the complete hashtable, you can create  a second hastable which can tell you which file is present at which index of first hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trie for each file. So, once the file is marked to be deleted, then parse through the trie and for each word in the trie, delete the corresponding key from the Hash Map . And then delete trie.
Or else, for each file you can create an additional Hashmap with key as string and value as 1 , to mark it as present. And once the file is marked to delete, iterate through the file Hashmap , and for each key , delete the corresponding entry in string -> file hashmap. 
The trie one will take less memory and will be probably faster then the hasmap one.